# Вывод даты модификации документа на определенных листах google spreadsheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Вывожу в google spreadsheets дату последней модификации документа в ячейке **D5**:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var d = new Date()
e.source.getActiveSheet()
.getRange('D5')
.setValue('' +d
    .toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes()+ ':' + d.getSeconds())
}
```

как сделать так, чтобы вывод был только на определенных листах, например **Лист3**, **Лист8** и **Лист15**?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно указать имя таблицы перед адресом:

```
getRange('Sheet!D5')
```

Comment: А как их перечислить: getRange('Sheet1!D5, Sheet2!D5') или getRange('Sheet1!D5', 'Sheet2!D5') ?